# Pandas read_json ValueError: Protocol not known

Tags: python, pandas

I ran the following code a while ago and it worked but now there is the following error. How to solve it?

> ValueError: protocol not known.

```py
import json
temp = json.dumps([status._json for status in tweet])  # create JSON
newdf = pd.read_json(temp, orient='records')
```

Comment: Can you share your json `temp` ?

Comment: @Psidom: it is just a json of tweets created by tweepy. The error was only when I ran the codes in an environment. If I ran it in base, there was no error. Anyway, this is the full error notification: `ValueError: Protocol not known: [{"created_at": "Mon Aug 24 03:00:06 +0000 2020", "id": 1297730373137453056, "id_str": "1297730373137453056", "full_text": "Dietary and Physical Activity Behaviors Among High School Students \u2014 Youth Risk Behavior Survey, United State... https`

Comment: *If I ran it in base, there was no error.* Then it's probably not a pandas problem.

Comment: @psidom: thanks. I am very new. Could you please suggest what packages to install in the environment in this case?

Comment: I don't think I can make a suggestion without knowing details about your environment. You need to figure out which line causes the problem first.

Comment: @Psidom: the 3rd line caused the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I could debug this issue is caused by an update of pandas.
The 1.1.0 update had changed few things on the read_json function.

I could make my code work when setting pandas version to 1.0.5

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html

Comment: Setting the version to 1.0.5 worked for me. I also tried the newer version 1.1.1 but this one didn't.

Answer (score 55):

The solution in my case consisted in using `StringIO` as below:

```
from io import StringIO
newdf = pd.read_json(StringIO(temp))
```

Looks like `pd.read_json` in Pandas 1.1 is no more accepting simple string.

Comment: just tested here and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: what does StringIO do to the json that make it work?

Comment: It seems like read_json now looks for a file-like object rather than a string-like one. StringIO provides a file-like interface for strings.

From the pandas docs: By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

Comment: The problem may be that the data includes a path or URL of some form. In my case, I didn't have to use StringIO() until the data started including a URL. I wish it would be easier to find documentation about this.