# Reading in json file pandas Exception has occurred: ValueError arrays must all be same length

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
path = r'\\xxxxxx\JIRA_BOW_11670.JSON'
load_df=pd.read_json(path)
```

Exception has occurred: ValueError
arrays must all be same length

I cut the json file short , only need ID and display name , cant read the file in

```
{"expand": "description,lead,issueTypes,url,projectKeys,permissions,insight",
     "self": "https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/11670",
      "id": "11670", "key": "FSD", "description": "",
       "lead": {"self": "https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=5e5fabed27b3910afc2fcd44", "accountId": "5e5fabed27b3910afc2fcd44", "avatarUrls": {"48x48": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/8b50ca39af21105162b4d362324f8b74?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FNM-0.png", "24x24": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/8b50ca39af21105162b4d362324f8b74?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FNM-0.png", 
        "16x16": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/8b50ca39af21105162b4d362324f8b74?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FNM-0.png", "32x32": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/8b50ca39af21105162b4d362324f8b74?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FNM-0.png"}, "displayName": "Ntombi Mahlangu"}
```

Comment: You could read the file with python's json module and extract the id and name from the resulting dictionary.

Comment: Can you paste/supply the exact file you are trying to load?

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'read'
  File "C:\Users\ab006qj.D_ABSA\Desktop\Py\projectid.py", line 58, in <module>
    data=json.load(path)

Comment: Trying to figure out how to upload the file to stackoverflow

Comment: Your json file requires one } at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem comes from pandas update. Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63581744/3958878

you can fix this problem by downgrading your pandas version