# REST API to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, api

I'm a complete beginner trying to learn how to use APIs to pull data then analyze that data. I was able to send a request to receive a csv which returned a 200 status code and prints correctly, but I can't seem to read it into a pandas DF. What am I doing wrong?

```
request = requests.get(host + endpoint + key, params={'format':'csv'})
df = pd.read_csv(request.text, sep=',')
```

Error message is ValueError: Protocol not known: contract_decimals,contract_name,contract_ticker_symbol,contract_address,logo_url,last_transferred_at,type,balance,balance_24h,quote_rate,quote_rate_24h,quote,quote_24h,nft_data,supports_erc_0,supports_erc
18,"akSwap.io","akSwap.io","0x82dfdb2ec1aa6003ed4acba663403d7c2127ff67","https

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong but also would love to know where I can go to learn more about using API data from pandas to construct a dashboard (something a little more structured than the docs would be great!)

Comment: directly `pd.read_csv( host + endpoint + key + "?format=csv" )`

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `pd.read_csv` function incorrectly.

Looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)...

> pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=NoDefault.no_default,  ...

> Parameters filepath_or_bufferstr, path object or file-like object Any
> valid string path is acceptable

The first argument of the read_csv function accepts a filepath or buffer. You are passing it a string object that you obtained from the api response `request.text`.

Try this instead. Inspired from [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553845/pandas-read-json-valueerror-protocol-not-known)

```
from io import StringIO
request = requests.get(host + endpoint + key, params={'format':'csv'})
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(request.text), sep=',')
```

You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) on the `requests` library you're using.

Depending on what API you're using, you should be easily able to coerce the API response into a pandas DataFrame using the standard functions available in pandas.

- [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

The pandas documentation is pretty comprehensive and [has good Getting Started docs too.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can read directly from URL

```
url = host + endpoint + key + "?format=csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',')
```

But if you need something more complex to get data from server then you can use `io` to create file in memory

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(request.text), sep=',')
```

If you would use `urllib` instead of `requests` then you don't need `io`

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

df = pd.read_csv(response, sep=',')
```