# Read a file in Azure data lake storage using pandas

Tags: pandas, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to read a parquet file which is stored in adls:

```
import pandas as pd
parquet_file = 'abfss://<>abc.parquet'
pd.read_parquet(parquet_file, engine='pyarrow')
```

But it gives the below error:

```
ValueError: Protocol not known: abfss
```

Is the only way to make it work is to read the file through pyspark and then convert it into pandas dataframe?

I installed adlfs

```
pip install adlfs
```

But now I am getting the following error -

```
ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches to make it work.

1. Downgrade Pandas version, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553845/pandas-read-json-valueerror-protocol-not-known)

   ```
     dbutils.library.installPyPI("pandas", version="version_number")

     dbutils.library.restartPython()
   ```
2. If first approach does not work, you need to get data in rdd first and then create Pandas dataframe.

   ```
   df = spark.read.parquet('<the path of your parquet file>')
   pandas_df = df.toPandas()
   ```

Comment: don't use `dbutils.library`! it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would recommend [mounting the storage](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) and query the data using this mount point using :

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('dbfs://mnt/<mounting_path>abc.parquet').toPandas()
```

Also, I would suggest using the [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html) to leverage the benefits of using Databricks. You'd keep the syntax of Pandas but would call the Spark API to do your computations. It's just as simple as :

```py
import pyspark.pandas as pd
```